# Assembly MIPS Copy String to Address

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to write a simple function in MIPS that copies a string to the address specified in the second argument. The first argument is the address of the string to copy. I wrote this:

```
.globl strcpy
strcpy:
lb $t0 ($a0)
beqz $t0 out
sb $a0 ($a1)
addi $a0 $a0 1
addi $a1 $a1 1
j strcpy

out: jr $ra
```

But I am getting unexpected results and I don't see what I did wrong.

Comment: Instead of `sb $a0 ($a1)` you want `sb $t0 ($a1)` since that's where you loaded your byte. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: You are also returning from the function without null-terminating the string. If you expect a C string-function to deal with the result, you will be disappointed. If the function is supposed to be an implementation of C's `strcpy()`, you also return the wrong value.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problems and can confirm it working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sb $a0 ($a1)` you want `sb $t0 ($a1)` since that's where you loaded your byte.

You are also returning from the function without null-terminating the string. If you expect a C string-function to deal with the result, you will be disappointed. If the function is supposed to be an implementation of C's `strcpy()`, you also return the wrong value.